# How to make row expandable and collapsible in datagridview

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview

I want to make `DataGridView` in which there are so many `Groups` and `SubGroups` and I want to make `Row` expandable and collapsible. Like if 'A' is a `Group`, in which three `SubGroups` values 'xxx', 'yyy','zzz' when I expnad 'A' `Row` then these `SubGroups` should show and when collapse 'A' `Row` `Subgroups`should hidden.
Like this image

[image]

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/expandable-and-collapsible-rows-in-datagrid-in-C-Sharp-winforms/

Comment: It is datagrid not datagridview

Comment: WinForms DataGridView doesn't support expandable rows, you will need a 3rd party control to get the result you are looking for

Comment: I have seen a datagridview control with row expand in a project but I don't know what is it.

Comment: Hi Check these links: [Master Detail Datagridview](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/835501/Master-Detail-Datagridview) and [Master Detail DataGridView in C# Windows Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/master-detail-datagridview-in-C-Sharp-winform/)

Comment: You can always fake the result by setting the row.Height=0 and back.. Do your planning and a few tests beforehand!

Comment: @NiranjanKala the link was for vb.net

Comment: You can 'collapse' a row by setting its Height = 0

Comment: Please elaborate more. I am not understanding which height. there is no option in property window for height. @TaW

Comment: There is no property editor for rows. But in code you can write things like this: `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = 0;` This would hide the 1st row. Of course you will need logic to control the hiding and showing.. I suggest adding a few columns dedicated to this, like the groupID, subGroupID and collpasedState. - Is your DGV data bound?

Comment: I am binding dgv by add column manually

Comment: OK, I was wrong. Changing the `Row.Height` can be useful for many things but not here. Instead simply make it invisible: `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible= false;` - you will still need to manage the controlling of the groups subgroups. How do you want to make the collapse controls? buttons, chaeckbox, images??

Comment: images of plus and minus signs. plus for expand and minus for collapse like in image I have uploaded in my question

Comment: OK, that is a little simpler than the checkboxes I have used [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30893451/image-alignment-in-center-of-rectangle/30895547#30895547) - Note that this is just a screenshot, not an answer to qour question. If you want I can show you more. I have inserted the grouping Rows in the DataSource. Have you succeeded in that yet?

Comment: Not succeeded. your example is good but not satisfacotry